# How can I save Admin server logs of weblogic container in my local file system

Tags: docker, weblogic

I'm using oracle image to start my oracle weblogic container and I want to store the Admin server logs in my **local file system** so that even if the container goes down or is deleted I should be able to access the logs.
How can I achieve that

I'm using below command to start the container
docker run -d -p 1000:7001 -p 1200:9002 --name aman_wls -v /home/aman/weblogic:/u01/oracle/properties 3e5b9fdf5fdf

I have my domain.properties file in /home/aman/weblogic

Answer (score 0):

Add to your command `-v /local/path/to/logs:/container/path/to/logs`